# I used AgreementCheckBox at my asp.net webform with CustomeValidator, but doesn't shows error message

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

**Code at AgreementCheckBox:**

```
 <asp:CheckBox ID="AgreementCheckBox" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" Text="Please accept our terms and conditions!" />
```

**Code at AgreementCustomValidator:**

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="AgreementCustomValidator" runat="server" ClientValidationFunction="AcceptTermsAndConditionsValidation" Display="Dynamic" 
  ErrorMessage="Please accept terms and conditions!" ForeColor="Red"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

**Server Side Code:**

```
 protected void AgreementCustomValidator_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs agrs)
 {
 }
```

Please suggest possible solution, thanks....

Answer (score 0):

When you use CustomValidator, you should set `e.IsValid` in the event to `false` if the input is invalid (you also need to check `Page.IsValid` when the form submits, because ASP.NET doesn't prevent yor form from submitting when there are validation errors).
Your code can look like this code:

```
protected void AgreementCustomValidator(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
    e.IsValid = AgreementCheckBox.Checked;
}
```